# Differences among .NET Capture, Group, Match

Tags: regex

I am making a small applicaiton using .NET Regex types. And the "Capture, Group and Match" types totally confused me. I have never seen such an ugly solution. Could someone explain their usage for me? Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have an example regular expression you want us to explain it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a simpler example than the one in the document @Dav cited:

```
string s0 = @"foo%123%456%789";
Regex r0 = new Regex(@"^([a-z]+)(?:%([0-9]+))+$");
Match m0 = r0.Match(s0);
if (m0.Success)
{
  Console.WriteLine(@"full match: {0}", m0.Value);
  Console.WriteLine(@"group #1: {0}", m0.Groups[1].Value);
  Console.WriteLine(@"group #2: {0}", m0.Groups[2].Value);
  Console.WriteLine(@"group #2 captures: {0}, {1}, {2}",
                    m0.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value,
                    m0.Groups[2].Captures[1].Value,
                    m0.Groups[2].Captures[2].Value);
}
```

result:

`full match: foo%123%456%789`
`group #1: foo`
`group #2: 789`
`group #2 captures: 123, 456, 789`

The `full match` and `group #1` results are straightforward, but the others require some explanation.  Group #2, as you can see, is inside a non-capturing group that's controlled by a `+` quantifier.  It matches three times, but if you request its `Value`, you only get what it matched the third time around--the final capture.  Similarly, if you use the `$2` placeholder in a replacement string, the final capture is what gets inserted in its place.

In most regex flavors, that's all you can get; each intermediate capture is overwritten by the next and lost; .NET is almost unique in preserving all of the captures and making them available after the match is performed.  You can access them directly as I did here, or iterate through the `CaptureCollection` as you would a `MatchCollection`.  There's no equivalent for the `$1`-style replacement-string placeholders, though.

So the reason the API design is so ugly (as you put it) is twofold: first it was adapted from Perl's integral regex support to .NET's object-oriented framework; then the `CaptureCollection` structure was grafted onto it.  Perl 6 offers a much cleaner solution, but the authors accomplished that by rewriting Perl practically from scratch and throwing backward compatibility out the window.

Comment: Hi, thanks Alan. Just 2 more question, there're a property named "Captures" for both Match and Group, what's the difference between Match.Captures and Group.Captures? And why is the Match.Groups[0] always the same as the Match.Value?  Thanks again.

Comment: A Match ISA Group ISA Capture, so Match inherits `Captures` from Group and `Value` from Capture.  The Match is the zero'th Group, so `Match.Captures` is simply a one-element list containing the whole match--as if we needed *another* way to refer to it!  `Value` is obviously the preferred way, being so much shorter and more intuitive.  But even that's optional if you use the Match/Group/Capture reference that expects a string, because `ToString()` just delegates to `Value`.

Comment: As for *why* the Match is the zero'th Group, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248213/in-c-regular-expression-why-does-the-initial-match-show-up-in-the-groups/2248767#2248767

Comment: Thanks, Alan. I will read the links. I'll let you know when I understand it. =8^D

Comment: Hi, Alan, I have read about the link you provided. Though there're many other explanations, I agree with you on that Match.Group[0] is used for the whole match because RegEx captures is 1-based. That's exactly what I have assumed. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

A match is the result of any individual match of the *entirety* of a regex. Groups and Captures both have something to do with capture groups (each `(expression)` from within the regex), but vary in how they behave. Here's a quote from the MSDN article on the Capture class that explains the difference:

> If you do not apply a quantifier to a
>   capturing group, the Group.Captures
>   property returns a CaptureCollection
>   with a single Capture object that
>   provides information about the same
>   capture as the Group object. If you do
>   apply a quantifier to a capturing
>   group, the Group.Index, Group.Length,
>   and Group.Value properties provide
>   information only about the last
>   captured group, whereas the Capture
>   objects in the CaptureCollection
>   provide information about all
>   subexpression captures. The example
>   provides an illustration.
>
> ([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.aspx))