# Is there a regex flavor that allows me to count the number of repetitions matched by the * and + operators?

Tags: .net, regex, matching, repeat, capturing-group

Is there a regex flavor that allows me to count the number of repetitions matched by the `*` and `+` operators? I'd specifically like to know if it's possible under the .NET Platform.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're fortunate because in fact .NET regex does this (which I think is quite unique). Essentially in every `Match`, each `Group` stores every `Captures` that was made.

So you can count how many times a repeatable pattern matched an input by:

- Making it a capturing group
- Counting how many captures were made by that group in each match

  - You can iterate through individual capture too if you want!

Here's an example:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\b(hu?a)+\b");

var text = "hahahaha that's funny but not huahuahua more like huahahahuaha";
foreach (Match m in r.Matches(text)) {
   Console.WriteLine(m + " " + m.Groups[1].Captures.Count);
}
```

This prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/LvST7)):

```
hahahaha 4
huahuahua 3
huahahahuaha 5
```

#### API references

- [`CaptureCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capturecollection_members%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250335/differences-among-net-capture-group-match and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320823/whats-the-difference-between-groups-and-captures-in-net-regular-expressions

Answer (score 3):

You can use parentheses in the expression to create a group and then use the `+` or `*` operator on the group. The [`Captures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures.aspx) property of the [`Group`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxdt1k3b.aspx) can be used to determine how many times it was matched. The following example counts the number of consecutive lower-case letters at the start of a string:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^([a-z])+");
var match = regex.Match("abc def");

if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Captures.Count);
}
```

Comment: +1; I also added an example where the answer is not the same as match string length.

Answer (score 0):

how about taking `"pref ([a-z]+) suff"`

then use groups to capture that [a-z]+ in the bracket and find its length?

You can use this length for subsequent matching as well.

Comment: not applicable to repetition of general pattern (see my answer for example), but obviously if the pattern matches exactly one character this would work