# Regex matching key="value" pattern

Tags: c#, regex, string

I want to match following pattern:

```
key="value" key="value" key="value" key="value" ...
```

where key and value are [a-z0-9]+, both should be grouped (2 groups, the " - chars can be matched or skipped)

input that  should not be matched:
 key="value"key="value" (no space between pairs)

For now I got this(not .NET syntax):

```
([a-z0-9]+)=(\"[a-z0-9]+\")(?=\s|$)
```

the problem with that, that it matches key4="value4" in input:

```
 key3="value3"key4="value4"
```

Comment: why do you need regex here? you could just split on space and get your pairs

Comment: I agree. Don't use regexps unless you need them for non trivial patterns. This is simply splitting on space.

Comment: can you please provide an example of what  you mean?

Comment: Are you trying to parse XML attributes with Regex? Surely doable, but in that case it is easier to use the integrated XML parsing in C#, e.g. but not exclusively LINQ to XML.

Comment: Residuum, its not XML attributes. It's something else, private syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec isn't very clear, but you can try:

```
(?<!\S)([a-z0-9]+)=("[a-z0-9]+")(?!\S)
```

Or, as a C# string literal:

```
"(?<!\\S)([a-z0-9]+)=(\"[a-z0-9]+\")(?!\\S)"
```

This uses a negative lookarounds to ensure that the the key-value pair is neither preceded nor followed by non-whitespace characters.

Here's an example snippet ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/bUAP3)):

```
   var input = "key1=\"value1\" key2=\"value2\"key3=\"value3\" key4=\"value4\"";
   Console.WriteLine(input);
   // key1="value1" key2="value2"key3="value3" key4="value4"

   Regex r = new Regex("(?<!\\S)([a-z0-9]+)=(\"[a-z0-9]+\")(?!\\S)");
   foreach (Match m in r.Matches(input)) {
     Console.WriteLine(m);
   }
   // key1="value1"
   // key4="value4"
```

#### Related questions

- [How does the regular expression `(?<=#)[^#]+(?=#)` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092797/how-does-the-regular-expression-work/)

---

#### On validating the entire input

You can use [`Regex.IsMatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4.aspx) to see if the input string matches against what should be the correct input pattern. You can also use the same pattern to extract the keys/values, thanks to the fact that .NET regex lets you access individual captures.

```
   string[] inputs = {
      "k1=\"v1\" k2=\"v2\" k3=\"v3\" k4=\"v4\"",
      "k1=\"v1\" k2=\"v2\"k3=\"v3\" k4=\"v4\"",
      "    k1=\"v1\"      k2=\"v2\"     k3=\"v3\"     k4=\"v4\"     ",
      "     ",
      " what is this? "
   };

   Regex r = new Regex("^\\s*(?:([a-z0-9]+)=\"([a-z0-9]+)\"(?:\\s+|$))+$");
   foreach (string input in inputs) {
     Console.Write(input);
     if (r.IsMatch(input)) {
        Console.WriteLine(": MATCH!");
        Match m = r.Match(input);
        CaptureCollection keys   = m.Groups[1].Captures;
        CaptureCollection values = m.Groups[2].Captures;
        int N = keys.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
           Console.WriteLine(i + "[" + keys[i] + "]=>[" + values[i] + "]");
        }
     } else {
        Console.WriteLine(": NO MATCH!");
     }
   }
```

The above prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/VTu5E)):

```
k1="v1" k2="v2" k3="v3" k4="v4": MATCH!
0[k1]=>[v1]
1[k2]=>[v2]
2[k3]=>[v3]
3[k4]=>[v4]
k1="v1" k2="v2"k3="v3" k4="v4": NO MATCH!
    k1="v1"      k2="v2"     k3="v3"     k4="v4"     : MATCH!
0[k1]=>[v1]
1[k2]=>[v2]
2[k3]=>[v3]
3[k4]=>[v4]
     : NO MATCH!
 what is this? : NO MATCH!
```

#### References

- [Is there a regex flavor that allows me to count the number of repetitions matched by the * and + operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029127/is-there-a-regex-flavor-that-allows-me-to-count-the-number-of-repetitions-matched/)

---

#### Explanation of the pattern

The pattern to validate the entire input is essentially:

```
maybe leading
spaces       ___ end of string anchor
  |         /
^\s*(entry)+$
|          \
beginning   \__ one or more entry
of string
anchor
```

Where each entry is:

```
key=value(\s+|$)
```

That is, a key/value pair followed by either spaces or the end of the string.

Comment: This is good, a small question: is it possible using regex not match anything if there is a miss match in input? Or I must validate it after regex is completed?

Answer (score 2):

I think SilentGhost proposal is about using String.Split()

Like this :

```
String keyValues = "...";

foreach(String keyValuePair in keyValues.Split(' '))
    Console.WriteLine(keyValuePair);
```

This is definitively faster and simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookbehind like you used your lookahead:

```
(?<=\s|^)([a-z0-9]+)=(\"[a-z0-9]+\")(?=\s|$)
```

Answer (score 1):

I second [Jens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100476/regex-matching-keyvalue-pattern/3100491#3100491) (but am still too puny to comment on others' answers).

Also, I've found [this Regular Expressions Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info) site to be quite awesome. There's a section on Lookaround about halfway down on the [Advanced](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html) page, and some further notes about [Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind).