# Regexp matching attributes for html element

Tags: regex

I'm working on a regular expression pattern to extract tag and attributes from an html element. But I have some problems with matching the attributes :s. Only the last attribute is stored into the matches array.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $subject = '<font face="arial" size="1" color="red">hello world!</font>';
    $find= '/<(?P<tag>\w+)\s+((?P<attr>\w+)=(?P<value>[^\s""\'>]+|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')\s*)*\/?>/si';

    preg_match_all( $find, $subject, $matches );
?>
```

Can someone help me out?

Many thanks

Comment: Drop that and use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp) instead.

Comment: You can't reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. See the awesome rant on this subject here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: But what if I want to parse html to xhtml? I read that xpath is xhtml compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Some important points:

- You shouldn't use regex to parse HTML. PHP has many excellent HTML parsing libraries.
- A group that captures repeatedly in a match only keeps the last capture.

  - One notable exception is .NET regex

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Brackets for Capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

#### Related questions

- [Robust, Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)
- [Is there a regex flavor that allows me to count the number of repetitions matched by the * and + operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029127/is-there-a-regex-flavor-that-allows-me-to-count-the-number-of-repetitions-matched/) (Yes! .NET keeps all intermediate captures!)

Comment: This is the better read: http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html - Capturing a repeated group vs repeating a capturing group.