# Regular Expression working in regex tester, but not in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I've searched around a bit, but it's hard to tell if this exact question has been answered before. I know you'll let me know if this is a duplicate.

I have a regular expression that matches a series of one or more positive integers preceded by a backslash. For example: \12345 would match, but \1234f or 12345 would not match.

The regex I'm using is **^\\(\d+)$**

When I test the expression using various testers it works. For example, see: http://regex101.com/r/cY2bI1/1

However, when I implement it in the following c# code, I fail to get a match.

The implementation:

```
public string ParseRawUrlAsAssetNumber(string rawUrl) {
    var result = string.Empty;
    const string expression = @"^\\([0-9]+)$";
    var rx = new Regex(expression);
    var matches = rx.Matches(rawUrl);
    if (matches.Count > 0)
    {
        result = matches[0].Value;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The failing test (NUnit):

```
[Test]
public void ParseRawUrlAsAssetNumber_Normally_ParsesTheUrl() {
    var f = new Forwarder();
    var validRawUrl = @"\12345";
    var actualResult = f.ParseRawUrlAsAssetNumber(validRawUrl);
    var expectedResult = "12345";
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
}
```

The test's output:

```
Expected string length 5 but was 6. Strings differ at index 0.
Expected: "12345"
But was:  "\\12345"
-----------^
```

Any ideas?

**Resolution:**

Thanks everyone for the input. In the end I took the following route based on your recommendations, and it is passing tests now.

```
public string ParseRawUrlAsAssetNumber(string rawUrl)
{
    var result = string.Empty;
    const string expression = @"^\\([0-9]+)$";
    var rx = new Regex(expression);
    var matches = rx.Matches(rawUrl);
    if (matches.Count > 0)
    {
        result = matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
var rx = new Regex(Regex.Escape(expression));
```

By escaping your expression you're turning all your special regex characters into literals. Calling `Regex.Escape(@"^\\(\d+)$")` will return `"\^\\\\\(\\d\+\)\$"`, which will *only* match the literal string `"^\\(\d+)$"`

Try just this:

```
var rx = new Regex(expression);
```

See MSDN: [`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) for a full explanation and examples of how this method is intended to be used.

---

Given your updated question, it seems like you also have an issue here:

```
result = matches[0].Value;
```

This will return the *entire* matched substring, not just the first capture group. For that you'll have to use:

```
result = matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Oops, that was an old version of the code. I'll make an edit and show the current version (the problem still exists).

Comment: See my updated answer. Also, while it's fine to edit the question to provide more information, please try not to edit it in a way that largely invalidates the answers. If you must, post the updated code under the original code and clearly mark it as an edit.

Comment: Ah, very good. I wasn't aware that matches[0] would return the full substring. Thanks.

Comment: Good point about editing the post in that way. I'll avoid that in the future.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. But your solution will throw an ArgumentOutOfRange exception. Only one match will be here. See my answer - OP should use Group value instead

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Yes, I noticed the error after posting my initial update. Please check again.

Answer (score 3):

Don't escape pattern. Also simply use `Regex.Match` thus you are going to have single match here. Use `Match.Success` to check if input matched your pattern. And return **group** value - digits are in group of your matched expression:

```
public string ParseRawUrlAsAssetNumber(string rawUrl)
{            
    const string pattern = @"^\\(\d+)$";

    var match = Regex.Match(rawUrl, pattern);
    if (!match.Success)
        return String.Empty;

    return match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: +1 For the clean re-write, but the `if` is not necessary either. Even if it fails to match `.Groups[1].Value` will be an empty string.

Comment: @p.s.w.g thanks! Didn't know about this trick with empty group returned by default. Very cool. Whole method can be written as `return Regex.Match(rawUrl, @"^\\(\d+)$").Groups[1].Value`

Answer (score 1):

What if you try get the group result instead?

`match.Groups[1].Value`

When I get to a real computer I'll test, but seems like it should work

Comment: Yes, it should be the solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375873/regular-expression-groups-in-c-sharp

    match.Groups[0] is always the same as match.Value, which is the entire match.
    match.Groups[1] is the first capturing group in your regular expression.