# Regex.IsMatch returns two different output in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find match between a string and pattern using Regex.IsMatch(). I framed the regex and tested it using regex101.com it works fine. Now problem is that
`Regex.IsMatch(filename, curSetting.RegExMatch.ToString());` returns true
`curSetting.RegExMatch.IsMatch(filename))` returns false for same filename. Can someone explain how does this differ and what is the difference between them?

`RegExMatch` is my regex member of `curSetting` object. Test data in my case is Pattern is

```
Gen(?!.*(?:erallog))(?<SerialNo>.+?)-(?<Year>(?:\d{2}))(?<Month>\d{2})(?<Day>\d{‌2})(?<Other>.*?\.log‌)
```

The string is `1_GeneralLog1370013-170403.log`.

Comment: Please share the full relevant code. What is the `curSetting.RegExMatch` pattern? What is `filename` value?

Comment: It would be helpfull when you are posting the pattern and the text you are searching in. And maybe this will help you [Regular Expression working in regex tester, but not in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687028/regular-expression-working-in-regex-tester-but-not-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What type is `RegExMatch`? Never heard of it.

Comment: `RegExMatch` is my regex member of `curSetting` object. Test data in my case is Pattern is `Gen(?!.*(?:erallog))(?<SerialNo>.+?)-(?<Year>(?:\d{2}))(?<Month>\d{2})(?<Day>\d{2})(?<Other>.*?\.log)` string is `1_GeneralLog1370013-170403.log`

Comment: [I get *true* for both cases](http://ideone.com/ghbYHD). What are the flags  your `curSetting.RegExMatch` is compiled with? I guess you used `Regex.IgnoreCase`. So, what do you want now?

Comment: So, did my answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that your `curSetting.RegExMatch` is compiled with a `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag: the `(?!.*(?:erallog))` is handled case-insensitively and matches the `eralLog` in your `1_GeneralLog1370013-170403.log` input string, so the negative lookahead pattern finds a match and fails the overall match.

So, there are 2 ways out (depending on what you need):

- Either remove the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` from the regex object initialization or
- Add the case-insensitive inline option `(?i)` into the pattern:

  `(?i)Gen(?!.*(?:erallog))(?<SerialNo>.+?)-(?<Year>(?:\d{2}))(?<Mo‌nth>\d{2})(?<Day>\d{2})(?<Other>.*?\.log)`