# regex for extracting a number

Tags: c#, regex, match

I have a list of input-strings as follows: 
"PlusContent"
"PlusArchieve"
"PlusContent1"
"PlusArchieve1"

and so on, meaning that there are allways two entries that build up a topic {content, archieve}. Now I want to get the number (let´s call it postfix) at the end of that string. For this aim I used the following regex:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"Plus.+?(\d*)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Now I loop the matches (should be up to 2, the first is the whole string, second one the actual match if existing).

```
foreach (Match m in r.Matches(tester)) Console.WriteLine(m);
```

where *tester* is the current string within my list. But as result I allways get the whole string, but not its postfix. I tested the same regex on [regexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) and it worked...

Any ideas what´s going whrong?

P.S.: This is the whole code:

```
List<string> words = new List<string> { "PlusContent", "PlusArchieve", "PlusContent1", "PlusArchieve1" };
foreach(string tester in words) {
    Regex r1 = new Regex(@"Plus.+?(\d*)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    foreach (Match m in r1.Matches(tester)) Console.WriteLine(m);
}
```

But for some strange reason I get only the original strings from within the list.

Comment: follow the link that I shared in my post and get the captured group only that is captured by parenthesis `(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user3218114's regex is correct. Since the numbers are captured using grouping, you need to access them using the Groups property like below:

```
List<string> words = new List<string> { "PlusContent", "PlusArchieve", "PlusContent1", "PlusArchieve1" };
foreach (string tester in words)
{
    Regex r1 = new Regex(@"\bPlus\D*(\d*)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    foreach (Match m in r1.Matches(tester)) Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
}
```

In this case, m.Group[0] is the original string content while m.Group[1] is the grouping specified in the regex.

Answer (score 2):

Try with capturing groups and get the matched group from index 1.

```
\bPlus\D*(\d*)\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gA3pT6/3)

[Read more about capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375873/regular-expression-groups-in-c-sharp)

Pattern explanation:

```
  \b                       the word boundary
  Plus                     'Plus'
  \D*                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more times (most))
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (most))
  )                        end of \1
  \b                       the word boundary
```

Comment: Well, I also tried out with index 1, but that gives me a NRE, as the resulting collection has only one single element (the whole string)...

Comment: As I found out the regex itself was entirly correct, so all the "test-it" hints were not usefull at all... the problem obviously was accessing the groups. However, +1 for the second link (I actually figured it out by cruellays answer)

Comment: I have clearly mentioned that use index 1. Since I am not a C# guy. I just know about a little bit about regex pattern that's why I shared you link for code.

Answer (score 0):

May this will help with short Regex which will fetch numbers in any string as suffix.

```
\bPlus\D+(\d*)
```

Here's [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yV9lG2/1)

And if you're using Regex then you can get the numbers in $1 with above mentioned regular expression.

```
List<string> words = new List<string> { "PlusContent", "PlusArchieve", "PlusContent1", "PlusArchieve1" };
        foreach (string tester in words)
        {
            Regex r1 = new Regex(@"\bPlus\D+(\d*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            foreach (Match m in r1.Matches(tester))
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(m);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Regex.Replace(tester, @"\bPlus\D+(\d*)", "$1")))
                    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(tester, @"\bPlus\D+(\d*)", "$1"));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where is prefix `Plus` is gone. The number should be treated as postfix not for all words.

Comment: Sent you the full code updates in your code package, could you please update the vote if the solution code works for you? P.S. I've already checked with console application.