# Regex get the text after the match which must be the last occurrence

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract the string after the last occurrence of "cn=" using regex in C# application. So what I need is the string between **last occurence** of "cn=" and **\** character Please note that the source string may contains spaces.

**Example:**

ou=company\ou=country\ou=site\cn=office\cn=name\ou=pet

**Result:**

name

So far Ive got `(?<=cn=).*` for selecting the text after the cn= using positive lookbehind and `(?:.(?!cn=))+$` for finding the last occurence but I dont know how to combine it together to get desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try using the following *regex* ...

```
(?m)(?<=cn=)[\w\s]+(?=\\?(?:ou=)?[\w\s]*$)
```

see **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vrEtXl/3)**

**C#** ( [demo](https://ideone.com/XIpmDp) )

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class RegEx
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?m)(?<=cn=)[\w\s]+(?=\\?(?:ou=)?[\w\s]*$)";
        string input = @"ou=company\ou=country\ou=site\cn=office\cn=name\ou=pet";

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", m.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the last occurence of cn=whatever may or may not be followed by another subcontainers(\ou=whatever\). tried to remove the ou with escaped \ only but got a string "office instead"

Answer (score 2):

You could use a negative lookahead:

```
cn=(?!.*cn=)([^\\]+)
```

Take group `$1` and see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/GDZJDS/1). As full `C#` code, see [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/xvZ5bQ).

---

To only have one group, add another [lookaround](https://regex101.com/r/GDZJDS/2):

```
(?<=cn=)(?!.*cn=)([^\\]+)
```

Comment: can you please modify the regex to have it matched but selects the value without the "cn="? the match itself is working flawlessly @Jan

Comment: @pandemic: Just use another lookaround: https://regex101.com/r/GDZJDS/2, updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another idea by just using a [capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6376236/5527985) for getting the desired part.

```
string pattern = @"^.*cn=(\w+)";
```

- `^.*cn=` will consume anything from `^` start up to last occurence of `cn=` (see [greed](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy)).
- `(\w+)` first group captures one or more [word characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html). Here is a [demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XMr6Rm/1).

The extracted match will be in [`m.Groups[1]` (see demo)](https://ideone.com/fork/GJz0Pz).