# Fetching the text within "<<NAME>> " in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to fetch just the text within the double angle brackets:
from a text like this , However it returns me the whole string, while i just want to fetch the text within the double <<>> brackets.

```
line2="Name: <<NAME>>   (<<COURSE>>)"
var pattern=@"<<.*?>>";
MatchCollection matches= Regex.Matches(line2,pattern);
```

Am i doing it correctly , please guide?

Comment: You can test if you're doing it correctly yourself.

Comment: It gives me output in this format:  <<NAME>>  and <<COURSE>>, which is not what i want i just want the NAME and COURSE.

Comment: You should look into [capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375873/regular-expression-groups-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

Use this grouping construct: `(?< name > subexpression )`, like:

```
string line2 = "Name: <<NAME>>   (<<COURSE>>)";
var pattern = @"<<(?<value>\w+)\>>";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(line2, pattern);
string name = matches[0].Groups["value"].Value; // "NAME"
string course = matches[1].Groups["value"].Value; // "COURSE"
```

It puts the captured subexpression into a named group (here "value"). To access the matches use the `Groups` array, just like I did it above.

Further information provides the [quick-reference for regular expressions.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)