# how to split just only the outermost

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have a statement string like this:

```
    *
    | { table_name | view_name | table_alias }.*
    | {
        [ { table_name | view_name | table_alias }. ]
        { column_name | $IDENTITY | $ROWGUID }
        | udt_column_name [ { . | :: } { { property_name | field_name } | method_name ( argument [ ,...n] ) } ]
        | expression
        [ [ AS ] column_alias ]
      }
    | column_alias = expression
```

I need only the outermost items,so I use char `|` to split the content, I want to exclude any the `|` exist in brackets.
The result of the split is that it has 4 items, like this:

#1 `*`
#2 `{ table_name | view_name | table_alias }.*`
#3 `{
    [ { table_name | view_name | table_alias }. ]
    { column_name | $IDENTITY | $ROWGUID }
    | udt_column_name [ { . | :: } { { property_name | field_name } | method_name ( argument [ ,...n] ) } ]
    | expression
    [ [ AS ] column_alias ]
}`

#4 `column_alias = expression`

I tried some like `(?m)\s*^\|\s*` or `^(({\|\s*})({\{})?)({.+})$` but that just get me ONE item not FOUR items.
Thanks for @Wiktor Stribiżew and @Rui Jarimba help.

I has idea `(?<!\{[^\}]*)\|(?![^\{]*\})` and I get like this:

#1 `*`
#2 `{ table_name | view_name | table_alias }.*`
#3

```
 {
                [ { table_name | view_name | table_alias }. ]
                { column_name | $IDENTITY | $ROWGUID }
```

#4

```
udt_column_name [ { . | :: } { { property_name | field_name } | method_name ( argument [ ,...n] ) } ]
                    | expression
                    [ [ AS ] column_alias ]
                  }
```

#5 `column_alias = expression`

Now, I need some change to fix `(?<!\{[^\}]*)\|(?![^\{]*\})` and clear #4 ....

okey, I Find a pattern, may be it is not perfect but it is work. it like this:

**`Regex.Split(s, @"(?<!\{(?>[^\{\}]+|\{(?<D>)|\}(?<-D>))*(?(D)(?!)))\|(?!(?>[^\{\}]+|\{(?<D>)|\}(?<-D>))*(?(D)(?!))\})")`**

Finally, I would like to thank all those who helped me again.

Comment: Try `Regex.Split(s, @"(?m)\s*^\|\s*")` if all the `|` you need to split with are at the start of lines. If there may be `|` at the start of lines that should not be split with, do not use this.

Comment: Do you really need to use regular expressions?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for your help and sorry for my result sample. I want to split with `|`, but when I use `\s*\|\s*` to split, I get too many result, I need to without `|` in `{}` or `[]`, my mean is result just has 4 item like `*`, `{ table_name | view_name | table_alias }.*`, `{
    [ { table_name | view_name | table_alias }. ]
    { column_name | $IDENTITY | $ROWGUID }
    | udt_column_name [ { . | :: } { { property_name | field_name } | method_name ( argument [ ,...n] ) } ]
    | expression
    [ [ AS ] column_alias ]
}`, `column_alias = expression`
Thanks again

Comment: I did not suggest `\s*\|\s*`, I suggested `@"(?m)\s*^\|\s*"`. Let know if it helps. Else, you need a parser.

Comment: @RuiJarimba thank you for your help. I really wnat to use regular expressions.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, you are right. `\s*\|\s*` is not work. but `@"(?m)\s*^\|\s*"` get me just one item result not four items. thanks again.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, I try to making some parser for my self.

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = @"*
    | { table_name | view_name | table_alias }.*
    | {
        [ { table_name | view_name | table_alias }. ]
        { column_name | $IDENTITY | $ROWGUID }
        | udt_column_name [ { . | :: } { { property_name | field_name } | method_name ( argument [ ,...n] ) } ]
        | expression
        [ [ AS ] column_alias ]
    }
    | column_alias = expression";


    string pattern = BuildPattern();
    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline;


    // solution 1: using a MatchEvaluator(Match) delegate
    string normalizedText = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, GetNormalizedLine, options);

    // solution 2: using replacement groups
    string normalizedText2 = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "$3$4", options);

    bool areEqual = normalizedText2.Equals(normalizedText);

    Console.Read();
}

private static string BuildPattern()
{
    // '|' is special character, needs to be escaped. 
    // Assuming there might be some whitespace after the pipe
    string pipe = @"\|\s*";

    // '{' is special character, needs to be escaped. 
    string bracket = @"\{";

    // remaining text in the line
    string otherText = @".+";

    // using parenthesis () to group the results
    string pattern = $"^(({pipe})({bracket})?)({otherText})$";

    return pattern;
}

private static string GetNormalizedLine(Match match)
{
    GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;

    return $"{groups[3].Value}{groups[4].Value}";
}
```

Output is the following string:

```
*
{ table_name | view_name | table_alias }.*
{
    [ { table_name | view_name | table_alias }. ]
    { column_name | $IDENTITY | $ROWGUID }
    | udt_column_name [ { . | :: } { { property_name | field_name } | method_name ( argument [ ,...n] ) } ]
    | expression
    [ [ AS ] column_alias ]
  }
column_alias = expression
```

**EDIT**:

I'm not using Regex.Split(), as mentioned by the OP as I don't think it's necessary to remove the `|` character. To get an array with all the lines (excluding whitespace) is simple:

```
string[] lines = normalizedText.Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Some notes:

- I'm assuming that the `|` character to be removed is always at the beginning of the line, i.e. there is no whitespace **before** that character
- I'm assuming that there *might* be some whitespace between characters `|` and `{`
- I'm using parenthesis for grouping the matches (see [Regular Expression Groups in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375873/regular-expression-groups-in-c-sharp))

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for my result sample. I want to split with `|` and not in `{}` or `[]`, my mean is result just has 4 items like  
`*`  
`{ table_name | view_name | table_alias }.*`  
`{ [ { table_name | view_name | table_alias }. ] { column_name | $IDENTITY | $ROWGUID } | udt_column_name [ { . | :: } { { property_name | field_name } | method_name ( argument [ ,...n] ) } ] | expression [ [ AS ] column_alias ] }`  
`column_alias = expression  `
 Thanks again

Comment: @AlexChen please edit your question and explain what is the desidered output