# spiliting the string in c# but an term consist of " , " so i dont want it to be split ? I have tried this

Tags: .net, split, trim

```
string mystr = clause.Replace("\"", "");

whereArray = mystr.TrimEnd(']').TrimStart('[').Split(',');
```

so in whereArray i get this

```
"DigitalMedia","=","Snapchat","AND","Impressions","IN","14,15,24"
```

so Basically i want like this

```
whereArray[0] = "DigitalMedia"

whereArray [1] = "="

whereArray [2] = "Snapchat"

whereArray [3] = "AND"

whereArray [4] = "Impressions"

whereArray [5] = "IN"

whereArray [6] = "14,15,24"
```

and trying this

```
whereArray = mystr.TrimEnd(']').TrimStart('[').Split(',');
```

[this is what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0dTv.jpg)

Comment: Could you post what the string `myStr`looks before Splitting?

Comment: ["OrphanCampaignName","=","Snapchat","AND","Impressions","IN","14,15,24"] this is the string myStr  , i dont want to split again 14,15,24 as it is whole term which i will save and give to db as query in future

Comment: It looks like you're receiving a JSON array of strings. Why are you trying to manipulate it using raw string functions when you could just use a JSON library?

Comment: ["OrphanCampaignName","=","Snapchat"] this is one condition for now i have max 5 conditions but when i pick this value "Snapchat " it exactly comes in my registered array index but when ["Impressions","IN","14,15,24"] have this it breaks it differently 14 15 24 i want it in one array which i register to like whereArray[n] ="14,15 ,24" like this now i get this splited as whereArray[n1]=14   whereArray[n1]=15   whereArray[n1]=24

Comment: @damien-the-unbeliever can u tell or suggest how could i do that

Comment: Do your splitted values need to keep the quotes?

Comment: @AsheraH nope i dont need the quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RegEx with a capture group to keep all content between " ".
For example using this pattern:

```
".+?"
```

Please read [regular expressions groups in c# question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375873/regular-expression-groups-in-c-sharp) if you want a code example.

Comment: i used this regex "(?:^|,)(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)" ,  but i still left with this kind of string with me *" \" myCharacter "* so i run i loop and i remove the \" by whereArray[i].Remove(0, 2);   so for now it worked..i am finding more better way!

Answer (score 0):

i used this regex "(?:^|,)(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)" , but i still left with this kind of string with me " \" myCharacter " so i run i loop and i remove the \" by whereArray[i].Remove(0, 2); so for now it worked..i am finding more better way!