# How can I get the text of a <textarea> in a webpage?

Tags: c#, html, webclient

Html:

```
<body>
<textarea readonly id="txtImagename1" name="txtImagename1" rows="1000" cols="200">
testing
second line
</textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I get the text in the textarea by c# code?

> (testing\nsecond line)

Comment: Use an [HTML Parser](https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20HTML%20Parser&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=c%23%20html%20parser&sc=7-14&sk=&cvid=172C2E4BE729422BA366C1ACC78B7BE1)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dedicated HTML parser.

However, if this is a quick-and-dirty requirement, you *could* use a regex with a capturing group, something like this:

```
var html = <your HTML for parsing>;
var pattern = @"<textarea.*>([.\s\S]*)</textarea>";
var matches = Regex.Matches(html, pattern);
if (matches.Count > 0 && matches[0].Groups.Count > 1)
...
```

You can then extract the captured group (the part in round brackets in the regex) using something like:

```
var text = match.Groups[1].Captures[1];
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375873/regular-expression-groups-in-c-sharp) for more details.

This is brittle and I do not recommend this for re-use or production code.

Comment: thanks, does “var html” mean the source code of the website?

Comment: Yes, `html` here is the full block of text (HTML) you've posted in the question. If the source HTML contains multiple `textarea` elements then this will be trickier (and you really should use an HTML parser in that case).