# Split Regex matches into Groups

Tags: c#, regex

I have markdown content with multiple images where each image is:

```
![Image Description](/image-path.png)
```

I am selecting all images in the markdown content using Regex:

```
var matches = new Regex(@"!\[.*?\]\((.*?)\)").Matches(content);
```

I am getting 2 groups:

```
Groups[0] = ![Image Description](/image-path.png);  > (Everything)

Groups[1] = /image-path.png                         > (Image Path)
```

Wouldn't be possible to get instead?

```
Groups[0] = Image Description.                      > (Image Description)

Groups[1] = /image-path.png                         > (Image Path)
```

Comment: If you put part of your regular expression in parentheses `( ... )` then that becomes a capture group.  It's not just for precedence / order of operations.  Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375873/regular-expression-groups-in-c-sharp  Groups[0] will always be the whole thing.  but you'll have a Groups[1] and Groups[2] of your own design that capture the right portions of the text. like `@"!\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression Groups in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375873/regular-expression-groups-in-c-sharp)

Comment: For C#, you can give the groups a name, and specify `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` to only capture the named groups. `!\[(?<description>.*?)\]\((?<path>.*?)\)`

Comment: @Wyck That will give 2 capture groups, not a match and a single group with a different value than the match.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Maybe I misunderstood, but I believe this is all that is desired: ([evidence](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IRs8xk)).

Comment: @Wyck That will give you group 1 and group 2 and `Console.WriteLine(matches[0].Groups[0]);` will give you the full match which is too much looking at the question.

Comment: Yes, and actually it gives you 3 groups:  Group 0 (full text) Group 1 (just the image description) and Group 2 (just the path), which I believe is what is desired here.  Is it the indices of 0 and 1 vs 1 and 2 that you are hung up on?  It's hardly worth the effort to introduce a non-capturing group just to get the right indices, IMO.  The auto-captures are auto-numbered starting at 1 - knowing that, I suspect, is likely sufficient information to unblock the asker.  We can let @MiguelMoura decide.

Comment: @Wyck Yes, but group 0 is the full match, and group 1 and group 2 are the capture group values.The question just states group 0 and group 1.

Comment: Yeah, you're technically right.  And you've adeptly created a (more complicated) regular expression that satisfies that requirement (by cleverly making the subexpression be the entire capture group by switching to capturing data out of the assertions) But I believe that asking for the captures to be at indices 0 and 1 constitutes an **XY problem** and I believe the intent was just to parse the markdown into its fields.  I will provide an answer that uses a simpler regular expression as an alternate approach, just in case.  And I think my approach is simpler.  Yours is correct too though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the group 1 value is part of the matched string.

You could get the match for `Image Description` and only `/image-path.png)` in group 1 using a lookbehind and a lookahead with a capture group:

```
(?<=!\[)[^][]*(?=]\(([^()]*)\))
```

The pattern in parts matches:

- `(?<=![)` Assert `![` to the left
- `[^][]*]` Match any char except `[` and `]`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead to assert to the right

  - `]\(([^()]*)\)` Match `]` and capture in group 1 what is between `(...)`
- `)` Close lookahead

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d!%5c%5b%29%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%28%3f%3d%5d%5c%28%28%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%29%5c%29%29&i=!%5bImage+Description%5d%28%2fimage-path.png%29)

```
string pattern = @"(?<=!\[)[^][]*(?=]\(([^()]*)\))";
string input = @"![Image Description](/image-path.png)";

Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0]);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
```

Output

```
Image Description
/image-path.png
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to not include the brackets [] in Image description?

Comment: @MiguelMoura Sure `(?<=!\[)[^][]*(?=]\(([^()]*)\))`

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the relevant sections of your content text by using a capture group.

Compare your regex and mine, where I made a very small change by adding parentheses to capture the *Image Description* part of your content:

```
!\[.*?\]\((.*?)\)
!\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)
```

Capture groups are automatically numbered starting at index 1 so these groups are available as

- `matches[0].Groups[1]`: which contains `Image Description` and
- `matches[0].Groups[2]`: which contains `/image-path.png`

`matches[0].Group[0]` is still the whole match.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
            string content = @"![Image Description](/image-path.png)";
            var matches = new Regex(@"!\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)").Matches(content);
            Console.WriteLine(matches[0].Groups[1]);
            Console.WriteLine(matches[0].Groups[2]);
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Image Description
/image-path.png
```

Here is a *[Runnable .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IRs8xk) of the above.*