# How to properly access the value of a capture group in C# regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      var r = new Regex(@"_(\d+)$");
      string new_name = "asdf_1";

      new_name = r.Replace(new_name, match =>
      {
         Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
         return match.Value;
         //return (Convert.ToUInt32(match.Value) + 1).ToString();
      });

      //Console.WriteLine(new_name);
   }
}
```

I expect `match.Value` to be `1`, but it is printing as `_1`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove _ from pattern ?

Comment: @Selman22 I can't, the `_` is an important delimiter and I need to check for it. The point is, the `_` isn't in the capture group so it shouldn't show up. I want to make it work with the `_` as it is.

Comment: `match.Value` is the entire match. Use match.Groups[1].Value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the value of the whole `Match` - you only want a single group (group 1) which you can access via the [`Groups` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups) and the [`GroupCollection` indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25kfx75y):

```
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
```

Comment: I was trying the same with `match.Captures`, I am not sure of the difference.

Comment: @void.pointer: I believe the point of `Captures` is when a single group has multiple captures.

Comment: Apparently [I'm not the only one who's confused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320823/whats-the-difference-between-groups-and-captures-in-net-regular-expression). Thanks for your help! This works great.