# C# regex. Everything inside curly brackets{} and mod(%) charaters

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm trying to get the values between {} and %% in a same Regex.
This is what I have till now. I can successfully get values individually for each but I was curious to learn about how can I combine both.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"%(.*?)%|\{([^}]*)\}");

String s = "This is a {test} %String%. %Stack% {Overflow}";
```

Expected answer for the above string

```
test
String
Stack
Overflow
```

Individual regex

```
@"%(.*?)%" gives me String and Stack
@"\{([^}]*)\}" gives me test and Overflow
```

Following is my code.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"%(.*?)%|\{([^}]*)\}");
var matches = regex.Matches(s); 
foreach (Match match in matches) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: Your regex is just fine you need to use match.Captures[0].Value not match.Groups[1].Value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320823/whats-the-difference-between-groups-and-captures-in-net-regular-expression

Comment: Didn't see there is [conditional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) answer already. You can also try [`(?:({)|%)(.*?)(?(1)}|%)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3A(%7B)%7C%25)(.*%3F)(%3F(1)%7D%7C%25)&i=This%20is%20a%20%7Btest%7D%20%25String%25.%20%25Stack%25%20%7BOverflow%7D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the capture is in group 1 and sometimes it's in group 2 because you have two pairs of parentheses.

Your original code will work if you do this instead:

```
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value + match.Groups[2].Value);
```

because one group will be the empty string and the other will be the value you're interested in.

Comment: I like the adding the two groups together, I was thinking of how to get all the values from group1 and group2 and discard the empty ones.  He he... simple and sneaky!

Comment: That helps a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Similar to your regex. You can use [Named Capturing Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)

```
String s = "This is a {test} %String%. %Stack% {Overflow}";
var list = Regex.Matches(s, @"\{(?<name>.+?)\}|%(?<name>.+?)%")
           .Cast<Match>()
           .Select(m => m.Groups["name"].Value)
           .ToList();
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, I don't get what you are saying. This code returns what OP wants. See `Expected answer for the above string ` and compare with what this code returns....

Comment: You should have explained you are using groups with identical names, and describe the feature.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Seems like "what you dislike in this answer" has changed. No I won't explain anything. This is my way.... And I think this is more readable than your regex...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for -1, but I won't do the same childish thing for you.

Comment: I do not think code only answers deserve ANY upvotes. SO is a place for those who want to learn. Do not give fish, teach to fish. You openly say you don't want to share your knowledge with others - that is why I downvoted. If you downvote my answer, that would be childish, yes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It is just your opinion..... If you want learn how to use it, You can use the link in my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn how conditional expressions work, here is a solution using that kind of .NET regex capability:

```
(?:(?<p>%)|(?<b>{))(?<v>.*?)(?(p)%|})
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3A(%3F%3Cp%3E%25)%7C(%3F%3Cb%3E%7B))(%3F%3Cv%3E.*%3F)(%3F(p)%25%7C%7D)&i=This%20is%20a%20%7Btest%7D%20%25String%25.%20%25Stack%25%20%7BOverflow%7D)

Here is how it works:

- `(?:(?<p>%)|(?<b>{))` - match and capture either Group "p" with `%` (percentage), or Group "b" (brace) with `{`
- `(?<v>.*?)` - match and capture into Group "v" (value) any character (even a newline since I will be using `RegexOptions.Singleline`) zero or more times, but as few as possible (lazy matching with `*?` quantifier)
- `(?(p)%|})` - a conditional expression meaning: if "p" group was matched, match `%`, else, match `}`.

[image]

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/RgxFim):

```
var s = "This is a {test} %String%. %Stack% {Overflow}";
var regex = "(?:(?<p>%)|(?<b>{))(?<v>.*?)(?(p)%|})";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, regex, RegexOptions.Singleline); 
// var matches_list = Regex.Matches(s, regex, RegexOptions.Singleline)
//                 .Cast<Match>() 
//                 .Select(p => p.Groups["v"].Value)
//                 .ToList(); 
// Or just a demo writeline
foreach (Match match in matches) 
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["v"].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@"[\{|%](.*?)[\}|%]"
```

The idea being:

```
{ or %
anything
} or %
```

Comment: This matches `%something}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a combination of conditional anda nested groups:

```
((\{(.*)\})|(%(.*)%))
```