# Why is Capture not 2 items?

Tags: .net, regex

```
Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(\\d+)(\\w)");
Match m = r.Match("    123x   ");

MessageBox.Show(m.Captures.Count.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(m.Captures[0].Value);
MessageBox.Show(m.Captures[1].Value);
```

this gives me exception when run

Comment: I don't really know .NET, but I think you're supposed to use `.Groups`, not `.Captures`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320823/whats-the-difference-between-groups-and-captures-in-net-regular-expression

Comment: it's because `m.Captures[1].Value` is **NULL**. hence you got `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` error. What are your expected result?

Comment: Beacause `m.Captures` has Count of `1`, hence `m.Catures[1]` giving `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Answer (score 2):

`Match.Captures` is really [`Group.Captures`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures), since [`Match`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match) inherits from [`Group`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group), so it refers to the captures of the global group (group `0`).

This can be seen in the source of the [constructor of Match](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/RegexMatch.cs.html#af1eb853327fc5b7), where it calls the base constructor with index `0`.

```
internal Match(Regex regex, int capcount, String text, int begpos, int len, int startpos)
  : base(text, new int[2], 0, "0") {
    ...
}
```

What you want is [`Match.Groups`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups), or more specifically `m.Groups[1].Value` and `m.Groups[2].Value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string pattern = @"(\d+)(\w)";
string input = "123x 45w 63 94b";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
Console.WriteLine(matches.Count);
Console.WriteLine(matches[0].Value);
Console.WriteLine(matches[1].Value);
```

This the way to check for multiple please post your expected result