# How to capture the text wthin the brackets: (), using regex maybe?

Tags: python, ruby, regex, perl

any way would be fine. Perl, python, ruby...

Comment: If you have got an answer that solves your problem please check the marker next to the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In perl, you can use this one,

Have a look

```
my $test = "Hello (Stack Overflow)";
   $test =~ /\(([^)]+)\)/;
my $matched_string = $1; 
print "$matched_string\n";
```

OUTPUT:

```
Stack Overflow
```

Comment: You don't need to escape ( as it is part of class characters, you can simply do /\\(([^)]+)\\)/

Comment: @M42: Yes that's true, it's a part of class characters.Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. I love you all.

Answer (score 3):

You can match this regex

```
\(.*?\)
```

**Edit:**

The above regex will also include the brackets as a part of matched string. To avoid getting the brackets as a part of match (i.e. only match string inside the starting and ending bracket, excluding brackets) you may use below regex.

```
(?<=\().*?(?=\))
```

Comment: but please remember the match will include the brackets as well.

Comment: It would only match "(this)" not "(this) is (sparta)" because the ? means that it matches as little as possible

Comment: @NullUserException no this wont. The .*? will make it lazy instead of greedy and first right bracket will be matched.

Comment: @NullUserException: no, + and * are both greedy by default and non-greedy with ? after them.

Comment: The op want to capture the text, your regex don't

Answer (score 1):

Do you only want to match outer braces?

For example:

In Python:

```
s = "(here is some text for you (and me))"

import re
print ''.join(re.split(r"^\(|\)$", s))
# Returns "here is some text for you (and me)"
```

Otherwise:

```
s = "(here is some text for you (and me))"

import re
print [text for text in re.split(r"[()]", s) if text]
# Returns "['here is some text for you ', 'and me']"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### On capturing groups

A capturing group, usually denoted with surrounding round brackets, can capture what a pattern matches. These matches can then be queried after a successful match of the overall pattern.

Here's a simple pattern that contains 2 capturing groups:

```
(\d+) (cats|dogs)
\___/ \_________/
  1        2
```

Given  `i have 16 cats, 20 dogs, and 13 turtles`, there are 2 matches ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/fIzpQeKmTa)):

- `16 cats` is a match: group 1 captures `16`, group 2 captures `cats`
- `20 dogs` is a match: group 1 captures `20`, group 2 captures `dogs`

You can nest capturing groups, and there are rules specifying how they're numbered. Some flavors also allow you to explicitly name them.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Use Round Brackets for Capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

---

#### On repeated captures

Now consider this slight modification on the pattern:

```
(\d)+ (cats|dogs)
\__/  \_________/
 1         2
```

Now group 1 matches `\d`, i.e. a single digit. In most flavor, a group that matches repeatedly (thanks to the `+` in this case) only gets to keep the last match. Thus, in most flavors, only the last digit that was matched is captured by group 1 ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/bV3MiAvyAm)):

- `16 cats` is a match: group 1 captures `6`, group 2 captures `cats`
- `20 dogs` is a match: group 1 captures `0`, group 2 captures `dogs`

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Repeating a Capturing Group vs Capturing a Repeated Group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html)

#### Related questions specific to .NET

- [Is there a regex flavor that allows me to count the number of repetitions matched by * and +?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029127/is-there-a-regex-flavor-that-allows-me-to-count-the-number-of-repetitions-matched/)
- [What’s the difference between “groups” and “captures” in .NET regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320823/whats-the-difference-between-groups-and-captures-in-net-regular-expressions)
- [Differences among .NET Capture, Group, Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250335/differences-among-net-capture-group-match)