# trouble with $0 in regex.replace - c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

```
string value = "From: $0-$100";
string emailBody = "{From}";
emailBody = Regex.Replace(emailBody, "{From}", value, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I want to get value of emailBody after regex.replace.

Expected Output: From: $0-$100

Actual Output: From: {From} - $100

Can someone please explain me what is the reason and how can I solve this? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$$` in the replacement pattern to replace with 1 `$`: `string value = "From: $$0-$$100"`.

```
string value = "From: $$0-$$100";
string emailBody = "{From}";
emailBody = Regex.Replace(emailBody, "{From}", value, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The `$0` in your pattern is replaced with the whole match value and the `$1` is parsed as backreference to a non-existent group with ID=1, so, since it does not exist, the literal `$1` is passed to the result (as you expect).

Note that if you have a dynamic (user-generated) replacement pattern that should be always treated as a literal, just `Replace("$", "$$")`:

```
string value = "From: $0-$100";
string emailBody = "{From}";
emailBody = Regex.Replace(emailBody, "{From}", value.Replace("$", "$$"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(emailBody); // => From: $0-$100
```

See the [C# online demo](http://ideone.com/o7dMIp)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: No, [see this demo](http://ideone.com/088VxB) that you suggest. `Regex.Escape` is used to escape the *regex* pattern, not the *replacement pattern*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scape the $ sign, since it is used to substitute your capturing classes. I mean, $0, $1 .. $9 mean that you are replacing it by one of your captured classes. See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Y[ou scape them using another $](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions)

```
string value = "From: $$0-$$100";
```

**EDIT:**

Concerning the "group 0" - the $0 thing - check here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2248328/4911877

Comment: `\$` didn't work for me. I had to use `$$` like pointed out in the answer given by wiktor-stribiżew.

Comment: That's right. I dont remember trying it, maybe I just made a misassumption based on other regex engines. I did update the answer, thanks, @burnttoast11

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do a simple substitution (and you have user provided content), you can use the following form:

```
MyRegex.Replace(userContent, _ => "replacement");
```

Here we're passing a lambda that doesn't care about the matches and just explicitly returns the fixed replacement text for them.

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape curly braces.

```
emailBody = Regex.Replace(emailBody, @"\{From\}", value, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: You'll either need a verbatim string - `@"\{From\}"` - or you'll need to double up the escape character - `"\\{From\\}"`

Comment: No, you do not need to escape the `{`, let alone `}`. .NET regex engine is smart enough to understand that `{` and `}` with no number or comma-separated range in between are no limiting quantifier, and are thus parsed literally. See my answer for the correct solution.